# Get error in ASP.net but works fine in Access

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, ado.net

```
sql = "SELECT distinct Switch( Month(Date) = 1,'January' ) AS Month, SUM([Actual Values]) FROM Mytable group by Month(Date) having Month(Date) < Month(Now()) AND Month(Date) > Month(Now()) - 4";

connection = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
connection.Open();
oledbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
oledbAdapter.Fill(ds);
```

Error:
The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect. What does this mean and how can I resolve this issue? If a hover above the sql variable and get the sql while debugging and run the same sql in access it works perfectly fine.
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're using `Date` as column name which is a reserved keyword for Access SQL (see the reference [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/286335/list-of-reserved-words-in-access-2002-and-in-later-versions-of-access)). You can opt to change it to any other name or use square brackets to escape it as column name:

```
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Switch(MONTH([Date]) = 1, 'January') AS Month, SUM([Actual Values]) 
       FROM Mytable 
       GROUP BY Month([Date]) 
       HAVING Month([Date]) < Month(Now()) AND Month([Date]) > (Month(Now()) - 4)";
```

**Note:** Avoid using reserved keywords and function names (like `MONTH()`) for column name and alias identifiers as possible.